# Mongoose Mixed type field not getting populated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a json doc that has embedded document which is variable (but in json format). So I use Mixed Schema type.
When I save, everything works fine except the mixed type object doesn't get populated and won't save. 
What am I doing wrong here ?
Updating --> What I mean is - everything works as expected except the data node (which is suppose to be of mixed type)

```
My Document Example:
{
    "data": {
        "user_name": "username",
    "cart_items": [
        {
            "sku": "ABCD",
            "msrp": 1250.25,
            "discount": 10,
            "final_price": 112.22
        },
        {
            "sku": "PQRSDF",
            "msrp": 12.25,
            "discount": 10,
            "final_price": 1.2
        }
    ]
},
"template_id": "1",
"from": "x@gmail.com",
"send_status": 0,
"priority": 99,
"app_id": "app3",
"_id": "532a54aa1c76fba0874c48ea",
"bcc": [],
"cc": [],
"to": [
  {
    "name": "acv",
    "email": "x@outlook.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "pem",
    "email": "y@gmail.com"
  }
    ],
    "call_details": {
      "data_id": "01234",
      "event_id": 25
    }
  }
code to insert:
Schema definition:
 app_id : { type: String, trim: true },
    priority:  { type: Number},
    send_status:  { type: Number},
    call_details : {
        event_id : { type: Number},
        data_id : { type: String, trim: true },
        id : false
                },
    from :  { type: String,  trim: true },
    to : [addressSchema],
    cc : [addressSchema],
    bcc : [addressSchema],
    template_id : { type: String, trim: true },
    data:  {  any: {}  }

Code:
r.app_id = req.body.app_id;
        r.priority= req.body.priority;
        r.send_status= req.body.send_status;
        r.call_details.event_id= req.body.call_details.event_id;
        r.call_details.data_id= req.body.call_details.data_id;
        r.from= req.body.from;
        r.to = populate_address(req.body.to);
        r.cc = populate_address(req.body.cc);
        r.bcc = populate_address(req.body.bcc);
        r.template_id= req.body.template_id;
        r.data =req.body.data);
        r.markModified('data');


        r.save(function (err){
            console.log("add");
            res.send ("added");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you currently define your schema, it will only save the `any` field within `data`.

Remove the `any` embedded field from the definition for `data` in your schema.

So instead of:

```
data:  {  any: {}  }
```

Use:

```
data:  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mongoose does not handle the embedded document save automatically. You need to save the embedded document first and assign the object ID to the parent schema as reference.

Comment: I really don't need an object ID for the embedded object. I can save the whole thing as string - it works. But I want to save it as object if possible.

Comment: make your to, cc, bcc an array of object. Like [{}]

Comment: That already works. There is a separate schema I defined for those arrays